# Fill the empty rows on other slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

I have a 3 images in 2 rows of my slider then I want to show the other images on the second slide to fill the empty rows starting from first image.

```
<div class="slider">
<div class=""><img src="1.png"></div>
<div class=""><img src="2.png"></div>
<div class=""><img src="3.png"/></div>
<div class=""><img src="4.png"></div>
<div class=""><img src="5.png"/></div>
<div class=""><img src="6.png"></div>
<div class=""><img src="7.png"/></div>
<div class=""><img src="8.png"></div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
$('.responsive').slick({
dots: true,
infinite: true,
slidesPerRow: 3,
rows: 2, 
slidesToScroll: 1,
});
});
```